# Ruby: context switches when calling dynamically defined methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Here's some test code that explains the issue I'm having. The Child class calls methods on the Parent class. One of the Parent's methods defines a new method called `foo` on the Parent. After `foo` is defined, attempting to call it from Child class works, but the context is completely different (I can only access Child's instance variables, not Parent's).

<strike>My guess here that this has something to do with Ruby's closures. Should I use something besides a block when I call `define_method`?</strike> **Edit**: I tried using a lambda and a proc, but it changed nothing.

```
class Parent
  @foo = 'foo'

  def self.existing_method
    puts "Calling existing_method, @foo is #{@foo}"
  end

  def self.define_new_method
    self.class.send :define_method, :foo do
      context = methods.include?('bar') ? 'child' : 'parent'

      puts "Context is #{context}, @foo is #{@foo.inspect}"
    end
  end
end

class Child
  @foo = 'childfoo'

  def self.method_missing(*args, &block)
    Parent.send args.shift, *args, &block
  end

  def self.bar
  end
end

Child.existing_method    # Calling existing_method, @foo is foo
Child.define_new_method
Child.foo                # Context is child, @foo is "childfoo"
                         # (in Ruby 1.9, the context is parent, but
                         # @foo is still "childfoo")

Parent.foo               # Context is parent, @foo is "foo"
```

This result is not what I want. `Child.foo`'s response should be the same as `Parent.foo`'s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm getting different results from your example above. my Child.foo gives 'Context is parent, @foo is "childfoo"'

Comment: That's really strange. I'm running Ruby 1.8.7 (not 1.9), so maybe that is relevant to the discrepancy.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'm running 1.9.1 currently.

Comment: I can verify that the discrepancy came up somewhere between 1.8.7p174 and 1.9.1.

Comment: ... and that you get your problematic behavior in the 1.8.7 head, so I'd say that you're going to have to go to 1.9 for this to work how you expect.

Comment: I will upgrade Ruby and see what happens. Although, Pete has 1.9.1, and `@foo` is still `childfoo`, when it should be `foo`.

Comment: Confirmed. In 1.9, the newly-defined `foo` cannot access Child's methods, but it does access Child's instance variables. This is not what I want.

Comment: Here's the result from the 1.9.2 preview, FYI:

    Calling existing_method, @foo is foo
    Context is parent, @foo is "childfoo"
    Context is parent, @foo is "foo"

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Ben and Pete. I'll see if I can come up with a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, here's what I figured out.

1. Calling `self.class.define_method` actually defines an *instance* method of `Object`. That meant that *everything* received that new method, which is the reason for the apparent context shift (`Child.foo` was actually calling `Child.foo` and not `Parent.foo`). Whoops.
2. In order to define a class method, you have to grab the actual class object, which, for some reason, isn't `self`, it's `class << self; self; end` (yeah, I didn't get that either). The code is briefly mentioned here: http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html

Ruby makes my brain hurt sometimes. This code should return the expected results.

```
class Parent
  @foo = 'foo'

  def self.existing_method
    puts "Calling existing_method, @foo is #{@foo}"
  end

  def self.define_new_method
    inst = class << self; self; end # Do not understand this...
    inst.send :define_method, :foo do
      context = methods.include?(:bar) ? 'child' : 'parent'
      puts "Context is #{context}, @foo is #{@foo.inspect}"
    end
  end
end

class Child
  @foo = 'childfoo'

  def self.method_missing(*args, &block)
    return unless args.length > 0
    Parent.send args.shift, *args, &block
  end

  def self.bar
  end
end

Child.existing_method     # Calling existing_method, @foo is foo
Child.define_new_method
Child.foo                 # Context is parent, @foo is "foo"
Parent.foo                # Context is parent, @foo is "foo"
```

Comment: Here's a Why the Lucky Stiff article that explains metaclasses in detail: http://dannytatom.github.com/metaid/

Comment: class << self; self; end => That is a singleton class, not required to add class-level methods. It depends what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

That's funny; I think Yehuda Katz's post from today explains *exactly* what you want: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/15/abstractqueryfactoryfactories-and-alias_method_chain-the-ruby-way/

---

EDIT: Okay - it's not "what you're asking for", on second thought, since it's not metaprogramming, but it's most likely closer to what you want to do. As far as your specific answer, I'll take a look at the code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Trevoke. I'll take a look at the post when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9x,

'methods' method return `Symbol(method name) Array`.

Therefore use `respond_to` method:

```
context = respond_to?(:bar) ? 'child' : 'parent'
```